# SSIS - Execute package task hangs

Tags: sql-server, ssis

i have a master package that runs 2 different child packages using "Execute Package" tasks. The packages are setup to run in order using precedence, but i'm have a problem where all packages say they've executed successfully, even when the loading icon is still shown, and the first package in the list hasn't processed all the rows it should have.

If it helps, both child packages read from a SQL server DB and write to an excel file.

Thanks,

Gonzalo

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that FailPackageOnFailure=true and that the maximum error count=1 on is set on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

There could be one solution for this. In OLE DB Destination, set "Data access mode" to be "Table or view" instead of "Table or view - fast load".